# Use SOS.dll from Windbg extension

Tags: plugins, windbg, sos

I am trying to write a plugin for windbg using the wdbgexts.h and was wondering if there was a way for me to use SOS.dll from my windbg extension so that I don't need to redefine a ton of structures. I can't seem to find any information on if its header is available and I have tried digging through the Windows 10 SDK which is where I found examples for writing a extension.

If the header is not available would I basically need to rebuild the structures I need from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/tree/main/src/SOS/Strike) to interact with managed code?

Comment: check AddExtension , CallExtension , GetExtensionFunctions From IDebugControl (dbgeng  interface ) wdgexts is kinda old try using dbgeng or teh c++ wrapper to dbgeng ExtExtension